# Realm Swift: store List of enum with primitive type

Tags: swift, realm

Is it possible to use a `List` to store an array of enum values? The compiler doesn't complain if I include `RealmCollectionValue` in the enum definition, but I'm not convinced this is supported since the supported primitive types include extensions with a function `func _rlmArray() -> RLMArray<AnyObject>` and I'm not sure how the `rawValue` figures into this.

For example:

```
enum AlarmOffset: Int, RealmCollectionValue {

    case dayOfEvent = 0
    case oneDay = -1
    case twoDays = -2
    case sevenDays = -7
    case thirtyDays = -30

}

class UserPreferences: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString

    let alarmOffsets = List<AlarmOffset>()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Realm Swift v10.10.0, you can declare any `RawRepresentable` enum as conforming to `PersistableEnum` and use it as a property type on Realm objects and inside Realm collections. Note that this requires using `@Persisted` and not the legacy obj-c declaration syntax.

---

<s>This almost works by coincidence, but declaring your own types as conforming to `RealmCollectionValue` currently isn't supported. The types which can be stored in a Realm collection are annotated with that protocol, but implementing that protocol is not sufficient to make it possible to store a type in a Realm collection.</s>